# Ubuntu docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) Got permission denied

Tags: docker

I am trying to remove all the stopped container using the command  `sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

But its returns

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
>   "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
>   See 'docker rm --help'.
>   Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...] [flags]

Anyone can suggest me how can i remove all the stopped container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran sudo for your outer docker command, but not for the inner one. Your bash shell expands that inner command before the sudo runs. So you either need to run the entire command in a root shell, or call sudo each time, e.g.:

```
sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

You could also add your user to the docker group to avoid the need to sudo every command.

Comment: its work perfectly sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q) Thank you so much